# Facebook likes reset to zero after 50 likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, meta-tags

I have an issue where Facebook likes reset to zero after 50 likes.

This things are the same and have not changed at all:

- URL
- tags
- Title of page

Any ideas about what is happening?